# Composite 3-D and 2-D using Anamorphic Projection?

Tags: xna, projection

I'm working on a game which takes place on a two dimensional grid similar to the fluid background grid in Geometry Wars. It is implemented as a procedurally drawn spring system which may have force applied to the intersection points resulting in a [primitive fluid dynamic simulation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=crR-mw7H3pM).

Let's say I want to elevate the grid into three-space. One way would be to upgrade the whole world to 3-d. Then I could render the grid to a texture and map it onto a plane which could be placed in three dimensions. What I am more interested in, however, is how I might 'fake' it by simulating perspective using 2-D. For example, its easy to vary the horizontal grid spacing based on the cell's row in the grid. By squeezing it at the top I can create a visually convincing vanishing point, but the physics and interaction with the grid is not right.

I'd like to be able to layer the 2-D grid over a separate 3-D layer such that they appear to be one. Have y'all seen the impressive demonstrations of anamorphic projection recently [featured on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tBNHPk-Lnkk)?

Intrigued, I found another tutorial video which shows how to [draw anamorphically using pencil and paper](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PEfM0NK9XLY).

Anyone have an idea of how to approach the problem of creating an anamorphic projection space in 2-D that would line up with a given perspective projection as that of a typical 3-D Camera?

I envision that this would manifest as an array of weightings applied to each point in the 2-dimensional grid which I could use to modulate the physics forces that drive the grid, creating a more realistic spring system than is possible with a simple faked perspective.

Answer (score 1):

`screen space position (x, y) = world position (x, y) / z`

...The basis of perspective projection, I think this would be your starting point, assuming a [pinhole camera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera) (camera with infinitesimally small aperture) in both instances. Divide-by-z is what gives the impression of depth. You would need to match your divide by z in both projections, in order to match perspectives... and matching the viewing position goes without saying. Hence this is all going to be a lot easier if the viewpoint doesn't change... which, from what you've said, sounds like it's the case.